# swift IOS convert a function to custom class

Tags: swift, function, class

Can anyone please give me a click on my brain? I'm having difficulties understanding "Class" from Swift. 
every time i create a class (custom) i fail. so what i normally do. i create a function and use it over and over again. Just don't feel right.

for example.
I want to create a class so by just by accessing it, i can create UILabel without using the method below

```
func addView(title:String, fontColor:UIColor, fontType:UIFont, bgColor:UIColor, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat) {

    let myView = UILabel()
    myView.text = title
    myView.sizeToFit()
    myView.numberOfLines = 0
    myView.textColor = fontColor
    myView.font = fontType
    myView.backgroundColor = bgColor
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

I just dont know how to understand creating a class. 
Can anyone give me a good example? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes in Swift are building blocks of flexible constructs. Similar to constants, variables and functions the user can define class properties and methods.

In this case you don't need to create a [Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html). For more information about my statement you can look [here](http://krakendev.io/blog/subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why):
it could be a waste of resources , few `UILabel` customizations don't justify a subclassing.
You can create a more useful file named for example `Utils.swift` where you have a collection of your methods:

```
import UIKit

func addView(title:String, fontColor:UIColor, fontType:UIFont, bgColor:UIColor, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat) -> UILabel {
    let myView = UILabel()
    myView.text = title
    myView.sizeToFit()
    myView.numberOfLines = 0
    myView.textColor = fontColor
    myView.font = fontType
    myView.backgroundColor = bgColor
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
    return myView
}
```

In Swift you don't need to import your files to the other classes, so in your class you can do for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let myLabel = addView("hello world",fontColor:UIColor.redColor(),fontType:UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 30),bgColor:UIColor.redColor(),x:0,y:0,width:200,height:25)
        self.view.addsubview(myLabel)
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you neeed to subclass `UILabel` to make relevance variations:

```
    import UIKit

    class MyCustomLabel: UILabel {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            sharedInit()
        }

        init(title: String, fontColor: UIColor, fontType: UIFont, bgColor: UIColor, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
            let frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.text = title
            self.sizeToFit()
            self.numberOfLines = 0
            self.textColor = textColor
            self.font = fontType
            self.backgroundColor = bgColor
            sharedInit()
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            sharedInit()
        }

        func sharedInit() {
            userInteractionEnabled = true
            // add others common init features..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. understand your function part but can you explain little more about that class you've created? i don't understand the part where your override init(frame:CGRecT)  is override mean its compulsory?

Comment: When you write a subclass initializer that matches a superclass designated initializer, you are effectively providing an override of that designated initializer. Therefore, you must write the override modifier before the subclass’s initializer definition.You can find more information here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_325

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of UILabel. Then declare your custom initializer with your expected settings.

```
import UIKit

    class MyLabel: UILabel {
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
        // custom initializer
        init(title: String, fontColor: UIColor, fontType: UIFont, bgColor: UIColor, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
            let frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.text = title
            self.sizeToFit()
            self.numberOfLines = 0
            self.textColor = textColor
            self.font = fontType
            self.backgroundColor = bgColor
        }

        func initialSetup() {
            self.sizeToFit()
            self.numberOfLines = 0
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

Now create object of the custom class and add as subview of main view.

```
let myView = MyLabel(title: "demo title", fontColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), fontType: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), bgColor: UIColor.grayColor(), x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

Hope this will help you.